# tree.RandomForestExt classifier and importance variable in Weka

Tags: weka

I want to calculate the variable importance by using weka. I read "Implementation of Breiman’s Random Forest Machine Learning Algorithm" article that it uses tree.RandomForestExt classifier and it has importance variables. I have three version of weka and all of them have tree.RandomForest classifier and this classifier does not has variable importance. How I can download tree.RandomForestExt classifier for my weka tool?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the authors of what you're reading and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://s112088960.onlinehome.us/ml2005/Zip%20of%20OTHER%20Journal%20Paper%20Files%20NOT%20JOURNAL%20PAPER/Weka_Distro_FredLivingston.zip) will download you a Custom Weka distribution, made by Fred Livingston, where you could find RandomForest Extension.